# npm install error "Cannot find module 'dezalgo'"

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, npm-install

I tried to install node modules using npm install. But I am getting the following error.

```
npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND
npm ERR! Cannot find module 'dezalgo'
npm ERR! Require stack:
npm ERR! - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\readdir-scoped-modules\readdir.js
npm ERR! - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-tree\rpt.js
npm ERR! - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install.js
npm ERR! - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js
npm ERR! - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command.

> npm i dezalgo --force --save

Comment: I tried. same error coming

Comment: How about this one ?      npm i dezalgo --force --save

Answer (score 0):

```
npm i --save dezalgo --legacy-peer-deps
```

Comment: I tried. same error coming

Comment: Most likely the problem then is with your operating system. Try the following steps: 1 clear the npm cache. 2 Uninstall Nodejs - Restart your PC and reinstall Nodejs completely. Here C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\npm-cache